# Column Based Backwards Substitution Flop count

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, julia, linear-algebra

I have a function I'm trying to do a flop count on , but I keep getting 2n instead of n^2. I know its supposed to be n^2 based on the fact it's still a nxn triangular system that is just being solved in column first order. I'm new to linear algebra so please forgive me. I'll include the function , as well as all my work shown the best I can.
[Column BS Function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rk3l4.png)

```
function col_bs(U, b)

    n = length(b)
    x = copy(b)

    for j = n:-1:2
        if U[j,j] == 0
            error("Error: Matrix U is singular.")
        end
        x[j] = x[j]/U[j,j] 

        for i=1:j-1
            x[i] = x[i] - x[j] * U[i , j ]
        end
    end

    x[1] = x[1]/U[1,1]


    return x
end
```

1. To start 2 flops for the addition and multiplication
   []−[]∗[,]

The  loop does:
∑=−112

2. 1 flop for the division
   []/=[,]
3. Inside the for  loop in total does:
   1+∑=−112
4. The  loop itself does:
   ∑=2(1+∑=−112))
5. Then one final flop for
   [1]=[1]/[1,1].
6. Finally we have
   1+(∑=2(1+∑=−112))).

Which we can now break down.

If we distribute and simplify
1+(∑=2+∑=2∑=−112).

We can look at only the significant variables and ignore constants,

1+(+(1))(+(1))+2

Which then means that if we ignore constants the highest possibility of flops for this formula would be    ( which may be a hint to whats wrong with my function since it should be  2  just like the rest of our triangular systems I believe)
[Proof](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yauqH.png)

[Proof](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jVyD4.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the code has two nested for-loops, each one proportional to `n`, a quadratic runtime can be expected.

```
using LinearAlgebra, BenchmarkTools

function col_bs(U, b)
    n = length(b)
    x = copy(b)
    for j = n:-1:2                          # n*(
        if U[j,j] == 0
            error("Error: Matrix U is singular.")
        end
        x[j] = x[j]/U[j,j]                  #    1 +
        
        for i=1:j-1                         #    n*(
            x[i] = x[i] - x[j] * U[i , j ]  #      2
        end                                 #    )
    end                                     # ) +
    x[1] = x[1]/U[1,1]                      # 1
    return x                                # = n*(1+2*n) + 1 = O(n^2)
end

for n in 2 .^[1:10...]
    local U = triu(randn(n,n))
    local b = randn(n,1)
    @btime col_bs($U, $b)
end
```

nicely approaches the expected factor-of-4 increase in runtime:

```
  61.366 ns (1 allocation: 80 bytes)
  90.900 ns (1 allocation: 96 bytes)
  147.557 ns (1 allocation: 128 bytes)
  280.000 ns (1 allocation: 192 bytes)
  1.100 μs (1 allocation: 336 bytes)
  3.900 μs (1 allocation: 576 bytes)
  15.600 μs (1 allocation: 1.06 KiB)
  56.800 μs (1 allocation: 2.12 KiB)
  219.200 μs (1 allocation: 4.12 KiB)
  957.200 μs (1 allocation: 8.12 KiB)
```

Comment: Thank you @bardo I like your explanation! However although I see your point , I need it to be a mathematical flop count kind of in proof form. Similar to what I did bellow the function.             1: To start 2 flops for the addition and multiplication []−[]∗[,]
The  loop does: ∑=−112
2: 1 flop for the division []/=[,]

Comment: (timed out)
Welcome.  I added some counts above.
I am not a computer scientist, multiplication is probably still more costly than adding, but you should get the idea. O(n^2) usually hides leading factors, and that is often the fallacy when comparing methods: if the n is not sufficiently large, a O(n) method can be slower than a O(n).
See https://discourse.julialang.org/t/fastest-data-structure-for-a-priority-queue/68472